# Does a keypair need to be changed after 'git add' without 'git commit' to remote

Tags: git, security

I accidentally staged a private file to be committed to a Git repository on my local machine. If I unstage it with `git reset HEAD` or `git rm --cached` before committing & pushing to a public repository, will the file's contents still be private?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it'll be safe.

As long as the file doesn't become part of a commit and the commit doesn't reach a remote repository, the file stays in your local tree only.

Comment: OK. Thank you. So then, the same is true if I accidentally add my private key to a file that's already being tracked by Git? Will it still be secure if I do that and then `git add <file>`, `git reset HEAD <file>`, remove my private key from said file, `git add <file>`, `git commit`, and then `git push`?

Comment: You can use the `--dry-run` flag with push to see what the operation would do.

Comment: @mattdipasquale : you even don't need to do `reset` if you remove the content before `commit` and then `add` to add the latest content.

Comment: If he didn't do the `git add`, there'd be no need to do anything.  If he did do the add, `git reset` is necessary.  If it was ever committed, one of the commit-surgery tools (`git commit --amend`, `git rebase --interactive` or `git filter-branch`) is needed.

Comment: Thank you all. :-)